# Without sound synthesis, what is a good way of making a program that plays guitar notes from an array of stored sounds?

Tags: java, algorithm-design

Without sound synthesis, what is a good way of making a program that plays guitar notes from an array of stored sounds? 
What I have in mind is to make note as a function of vibration speed such as N (V) which returns an int index of the sound to be played and the vibration speed itself as a multivariate function of 3 variables distance, thickness and tension so V (d, t, n) = ₩ n  - ₩ t -  ₩ d;
Where ₩ is some coefficient foreach variable. And negative represents  an inversely propotional relationship. 
My qyestion may seem a bit broad, but how to improve such a model and is it mathmatically sound?

Comment: What do you mean by "a good way"?  What are your requirements, or what are the criteria for judging an answer?  What would count as "good" in your view?  Why do you reject "sound synthesis"?    It sounds like you already know one solution, but you haven't told us why you have rejected that solution.  That makes me worry you're going to reject other suggestions as well.  When you ask "how to improve" this model, what properties do you want to see improved?  What do you mean by "mathematically sound"?  Also, please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Lastly, what does this have to do with computer science?  Asking how to model sound production seems like a matter of the study of musical instruments (or physics), not a question about computer science.  Asking what is mathematical sound seems like a question about mathematics, not about computer science.